# How to remove related post from home page

Tags: posts, hooks, homepage, theme-thesis

I am using thesis i am displaying related post using bellow snippet code.My problem is that i dont want load related post on home page.with the css trick we can make it display none but it loads so i dont want load related post on home page.

i tried this condition `if ( is_home() )` and `is_front_page()` to load function for specific page  but its load the related post on home page.

can any body tell how do i prevent this hook to unload related post on home page witout css trick.

```
function my_related_posts() {

 $orig_post = $post;
global $post;
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
if ($tags) {
$tag_ids = array();
foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
$args=array(
'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'posts_per_page'=>12, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

echo '<div id="related_posts"><h3 class="heading033">Read More</h3><ul>';

while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
$my_query->the_post(); ?>

<li><div class="relatedthumb"><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> <?php echo the_post_thumbnail('medium') ?></a></div>
<div class="relatedcontent">
<h3><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

</div>
</li>
<? }
echo '</ul></div>';
}
}
$post = $orig_post;
wp_reset_query();

}
add_action('thesis_hook_after_post','my_related_posts');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
if(!is_home() && !is_front_page()) add_action( 'thesis_hook_after_post', 'my_related_posts' );
```

will do that for you. It will not do the `add_action()` when we are at the home page or not any front page.

If it doesn't work for you, may be you need to contact with the Thesis team.

Comment: if(!is_home() && !is_front_page()){
add_action('thesis_hook_after_post','my_related_posts');
} i have try this and i have added all code in if block but hook load related post on home page.

Comment: What if using `if(!is_home() || !is_front_page())`... if not working, you need to consult their support forum

Comment: this also not working